# Can't locate Switch.pm module even though it is there

Tags: linux, perl

```
Can't locate Switch.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Switch module)
(@INC contains:
    /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.1//x86_64-linux-thread-multi 
    /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.1/
    /usr/local/lib64/perl5
    /usr/local/share/perl5
    /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl
    /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl
    /usr/lib64/perl5
    /usr/share/perl5
    .
)
```

(Line breaks added for readability.) But when i try to locate the file, it is there in the following paths

```
/usr/local/lib/perl5/5.10.1/Switch.pm
/usr/local/lib/perl5/5.10.1/CGI/Switch.pm
/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/CGI/Switch.pm
```

I tried to add location of perl containing Switch.pm using

```
echo $PERL5LIB 
export PERL5LIB="/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.1/"
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$ANT_HOME/bin:$PERL5LIB:$PATH 
source /.bash_profile
echo $PERL5LIB
```

Even then its not able to locate Switch.pm

Comment: Why is it in `/usr/local/lib/perl5/5.10.1` but you set `PERL5LIB="/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.1/"`?

Comment: i set it to /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.10.1 also, then i got

Comment: Perl lib version (5.10.1) doesn't match executable version (v5.18.4) at /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.10.1//x86_64-linux-thread-multi/Config.pm line 50.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.10.1/Env.pm line 122.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.10.1/Env.pm line 122

Comment: You seem to have a very strange Perl set-up. You are sunning Perl 5.18.4, but you are looking for modules in a library configured for 5.10.1. That's not a recipe for success. How did you install Perl? How did you install these modules?

Comment: Isn't `Switch` deprecated? And the same goes for the feature `given/when`. Just use `if` statements instead.

Comment: Why are you telling Perl 5.18.4 to use modules installed using 5.10.1? Did you ever install that module using 5.18.4?

Comment: The docs at Perl [switch statements](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Switch-Statements) don't mention deprecation of `given`/`when` (but do mention version-dependent behaviour all over the place).  The [Switch](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Switch) module does say "Use `given`/`when` when you can".

Comment: the version of the perl installed is v5.18.4, but i want to install 5.10.1 now, how do i unistall 5.18.4

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments:

Don't do this. You're loading modules from an old version of perl (5.10) into a newer version (5.18). This is always a hacky bodge at best, and a source of glitches, chaos and axe-wielding maintenance programmers in your future.

Just install the library for the version of perl you're using. You *might* find perl 5.10 is installed somewhere, and will work - but it's quite an old version, so you may not want to go down that road, when updating things generally means improvements.